# Android Background Image Blurry

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to add a background image to my app. I have added the image into the drawable folder and referenced it in XML file. But whenever I launch the app the picture is very blurry.

Is there a way to fix this, or should I be getting my pictures from a specific Android website?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have had the same problem, what I found useful was searching for high quality images on google,  and if that doesnt get you any results try editing the pixels/cm or /inch in a simple image viewer, I used preview on the mac and it worked well for me

Comment: You know we can see that you're talking to yourself right?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a low resolution image on a higher resolution device, this will happen.
You should put higher resolution images in the different drawable folders.

You can read more about it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I have the image in the hdpi drawable folder, so should i just search for high resolution pictures instead?

Comment: HDPI ~ 240dpi ~ 94.5 pixels/cm

You need a picture with a resolution close to that.

Comment: This is a good website for converting dpi to px/cm:
http://www.endmemo.com/sconvert/dpipixel_cm.php

Comment: thanks. and is there a way of changing the pixels of an old picture to the new resolution?

Comment: Not unless you are a master of photo manipulation or the resolution is higher to start with. A graphic artist may be able to help you.

Comment: cool well thanks for all the help, ill just google for 94.5 pixels/cm and try that

Comment: If you design for one screen size, this is a good picture to convert to more: http://www.inpixelitrust.fr/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/screens-densities.png

Answer (score 0):

Normally the back ground image will depend on the resolution of the image you are using, try edit it the pixels/cm or /inch in a image viewer.